# Is there any way to programatically zoom MKMapView without it snapping to one of its predefined zoom levels?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, mapkit

I am using setRegion to have MKMapView zoom in to the region I have supplied. The problem is that there is very little granularity to this and it simply chooses the most proximate zoom-level and zooms to that.

Is there any way of having it zoom to exactly the region I have supplied or do I need to accept this limitation and move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently it zooms so that the map tiles aren't blurry, which means fixed zoom levels. The upcoming update seems to render on the fly, so you may be able to do it in the future, but for now you'll have to accept the region you get.

Comment: But you can zoom with the fingers, isn't any chance to do something like that with a UISlider or 2 buttons?

Comment: @jcesar The only way to set the zoom level is with `setRegion`, which always sets it to a specific zoom level, never between. iOS 6 may change this.